# Vim does :help have special window behavior?

Tags: vim

Disclaimer: Vim n00b.  If one of my assumptions here is wrong please correct me.

When I use `:help` in Vim a new window opens up with help information.  Normally if I have two windows and close one of them, the other assumes the full height of the screen.  This is what also happens when I close the help window - the original window resumes its full height.  When I close the original window, however, Vim closes entirely.  This is probably the behavior we would want, but it seems to be different from the norm.  Are certain windows special-cased not to stick around when other windows close?  What are the rules behind this behavior?

Comment: Yes, `help` buffers (and windows) are special. `help` buffers are "unlisted", this means that they shouldn't appear when you do `:ls` or navigate to other buffers with `:bnext` and friends. Vim simply quits when you close the last window containing a regular *listed* buffer.

Comment: Good question, been using Vim for a while and didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are buffers (that hold normal files that you edit), and there are `:help special-buffers`. One of them is `help`, recognized by `:setlocal buftype?` yielding `help`.

Vim has special logic that when `:quit`ing / `:close`ing another buffer, and only a help buffer would remain: the help buffer is automatically closed as well, and therefore Vim will remove the current tab page / quit the current Vim session altogether.